# How can I upvote a comment again?

Tags: support, comment, up-votes

By mistake I double voted a comment in [How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{-\mathfrak{i}a}}{x^2+bx+1} \,\mathrm{d}x$ using complex analysis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2529614/how-to-evaluate-int-0-infty-fracx-mathfrakiax2bx1-mathrm), and now I can no longer restore my upvote.  Is there anything I can do other than be more careful next time?

Background:  I made the mistake because I got out of sync, my phone was slow to respond to the first click prompting me to try another.  Maybe set up a time limit to decide either way?

Comment: I retagged [meta-tag:support] as I got the impression you are more inquiring about the current situation than trying to propose a change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unupvoting is very restrained, and it is by design that you cannot upvote yet again. That is to say, indeed you'll just have to be more careful. :-)

See [Cancelling upvote on comment?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/cancelling-upvote-on-comment) for reference.